# Unable to build Java 16 app with Gradle via Docker

Tags: java, docker, gradle

I have a standard Springboot application written with Java 16. This compiles and builds just fine in my IDE and via CI/CD etc.

However, attempting to move the building to a docker file and I'm hit with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Cannot invoke "javax.tools.JavaCompiler.getStandardFileManager(javax.tools.DiagnosticListener, java.util.Locale, java.nio.charset.Charset)" because "this.delegate" is null
```

I assume this is some under the hood thing but I can't figure out how to resolve it. I've tried different Gradle images with different builds of the JVM (Hotspot, OpenJ9) but all have the same result.

```
FROM gradle:jre16-hotspot AS build

COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/srcn

WORKDIR /home/gradle/src

RUN gradle build
```

Nothing fancy in my Dockerfile either. I'd love to understand why I only get this issue when building via Docker, and not when building in any other manner.

Any tips?

Comment: What if you try jdk image, not jre?

Comment: :faceplam: I completely missed that somehow, you're of course correct. Appreciate it! Feel free to switch it to an answer and I'll happily accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the compiler is available only in JDK, you need to replace the first line in your Dockerfile with:

```
FROM gradle:jdk16-hotspot AS build
```